# How to update a line layer in react-map-gl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I'm using Mapbox and there is this feature called `setData()` which is used to update a source and then triggers a re-render of the map (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/sources/#geojsonsource#setdata). This is exactly what I want, but unfortunately I can't find a way to implement this with `react-map-gl`.

Do you have any idea if a similar feature exists in this React framework, or how to update the line layer otherwise?